# Full precision output of floating point types in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, floating-point, ssms

I have the value `1555.4899999999998` stored in a `float` column with default precision (53).  When I do a simple `select`, SSMS rounds the output instead of printing it with all available precision.  It's caused some gotchas for me recently since the value printed doesn't work as a `float` literal to match the actual stored value.

For example (note that both of these numbers have an exact representation in the default `float`),

```
declare @f1 float;
declare @f2 float;
set @f1 = 1555.49;
set @f2 = 1555.4899999999998;
select @f1, @f2;
select STR(@f1,30,15), STR(@f2,30,15);
```

Outputs:

```
1555.49 1555.49
1555.490000000000000    1555.489999999999800
```

In Query Analyzer, that first `select` outputs:

```
1555.49 1555.4899999999998
```

That's the behavior I want to get from Management Studio.  Is there a way to prevent SSMS from rounding in its result display?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No.**

SQL Server Management Studio rounds floating point values for display purposes; <del>there is a [Connect suggestion to change this behavior](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/126117/ssms-disply-of-float-datatype), but it is closed "as By Design".</del> (Microsoft Connect, a public issue tracker for Microsoft software has been retired)

However, `SQLCMD`, `osql` and the Query Analyzer do not.

```
SQLCMD -E -S server -Q"SELECT CONVERT(FLOAT, 1555.4899999999998)"
```

Comment: I follow the link and read: `Microsoft Connect Has Been Retired`

Comment: Same remark as @BernhardDöbler. Could someone update link if possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you would rather use a float type than a decimal type?  Floats are stored as fractions, which causes them to often be slightly innacurate when doing operations on them.  This is okay when you have a graphics application where the innaccuracy is much less significant than the size of a pixel, but it's a huge issue in something like an accounting application where you're dealing with money.

I would venture to say that the accuracy of a decimal is more important to most applications than any benefit in speed or size they would get from using a float.

Comment: The database schema is outside of my control, unfortunately.  I am 100% in agreement that `float` is a bad choice for this application, but if it were the right type I'd still expect a more accurate representation in Management Studio.

Answer (score -1):

Edit to my original post.  I was trying to solve a slightly different problem when I ran across this page.  I just wanted a float type to return a "regular" number, not scientific notation.

Suggested two converts originally.  Wound up with this in then end.  The 7 below could be changed to show as many decimal places as you would like.  Replace and trims get rid of leading and trailing zeroes.

REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(STR(x, 20, 7),'0',' '))),' ','0')

Comment: The aim is not to convert to VARCHAR.  The STR() calls in my example already do that.  I had been hoping to change the default behavior of SSMS without having to add conversions to my query.  By the way, 5 places after the decimal point isn't enough to disambiguate the values in my example, either.  You'd need at least DECIMAL(28,13) for that.

Comment: I edited my answer.  Still doesn't help with SSMS.  Just returns the string representation I wanted.

Perhaps a useful workaround.