# Issue with SQL float round

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, sql-server-2012

Let's say a query like this

```
select (low + high)/2 'avg'
from tbl_values
```

when executed in SQL Server 2012 I get results like `166.65`,
but when I bind the same query to a C# datagridview it will be `166.64999999999998`.

Why is SQL rounding when I didn't ask it to? And if it's by default, why isn't it shown as rounded in the datagridview?

For a given query, the executed result should be the same for SQL and C#... or not!

Comment: "why is SQL rounding " - Printing/Displaying is rounding....

Comment: should I post the canonical link?

Comment: @mitch but why is 'printing' rounding to 2 digits after decimal point and to 3 in other records? I'm getting `166.65` and `286.335` .. yes please, links would be nice :>

Comment: Take a look at this [Full precision output of floating point types in SQL Server Management Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099575/full-precision-output-of-floating-point-types-in-sql-server-management-studio).

Comment: Related (not necessarily a duplicate): *[T-SQL rounding vs. C# rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41592666)*

Comment: @PeterMortensen I think your comment's place is on the other question since it's newer than this :)