# T-SQL rounding vs. C# rounding

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, rounding, sql-server-2016-express

I am using Microsoft [SQL Server Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Express) 2016 to write a [stored procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure). One of the requirements is to do rounding. But every now and then, the rounding is wrong. I found out that T-SQL rounding is not exactly the same with C#, but why?

Compare two rounding below:

```
In T-SQL: ROUND(0.045, 2) --> this will produce 0.05

In C#: Math.Round(0.045, 2) --> this will produce 0.04
```

Why does C# produce 0.04? Shouldn't it be 0.05?

What should I do so that C# rounding = T-SQL rounding?

---

Out of curiosity, I tried this in C#:

```csharp
Math.Round(0.055, 2)
```

Guess what C# rounded it to? It rounded to 0.06! Now, I am completely confused!

```csharp
Math.Round(0.045, 2)   // This becomes 0.04
Math.Round(0.055, 2)   // This becomes 0.06
```

What is the explanation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why-does-math-round2-5-return-2-instead-of-3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977796/why-does-math-round2-5-return-2-instead-of-3). Answer by Jon Skeet himself ;)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is because .NET defaults to 'ToEven' rounding, while SQL uses 'AwayFromZero'. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx#Round4_Example). These are different rounding methods, and they differ in how they treat 5.

AwayFromZero rounds it up to the next positive, or down to the next negative number. So, 0.5 becomes 1, -0.5 becomes -1. ToEven rounds to the nearest even number. So 2.5 becomes 2, 3.5 becomes 4 (and likewise for negative numbers). Numbers other than 5 are treated the same, and they are rounded to the nearest number. Since 5 is equidistant from two numbers, it's a special case, with different strategies.

ToEven is also known as 'Banking Rules', and it's the default used in [IEEE_754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Rounding_rules), which is [why](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round.aspx#Tasks) it's the default in .NET.

Conversely, AwayFromZero is also known as 'Commercial Rounding'. I don't know why it is the default of SQL Server, probably simply because it's the most widely known and understood method.

Of course, you can always configure what you need:

In C# you can do:

```
Math.Round(value, MidpointRounding.ToEven)
```

or

```
Math.Round(value, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

In SQL you can use [ROUND()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx), [FLOOR()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178531.aspx) and/or [CEILING()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189818.aspx).

Which of the methods is better, depends what you use it for, and what you want. For reasonable collections/distributions, the average of rounded toEven values is the same as its original values. This is not necessarily the case with AwayFromZero. If you have a collection with many `.5` data, rounding AwayFromZero will treat all those values the same, and introduce a bias.

The effect is that the average of the rounded values is not the same as the average of the original values. The point of rounding is making a value simpler, while it holds the same meaning. This is no longer the case if the averages don't match; the rounded values have a (slightly?) different meaning then the original values.

Comment: I was writing the same answer, with a different link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3 so +1 for your speed sir

Comment: Great answer! +1 I added an addendum via [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55542163/577765) as a compliment to this one, showing another approach to performing this type of rounding in T-SQL :-)

Comment: use the tsql round it is much faster.  Any time you have use a dot.net function it will be signficantly slower

Answer (score 5):

C# allows you to specify what to do in the midpoint rounding situation - see *[Round(Decimal, Int32, MidpointRounding)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131275(v=vs.110).aspx)*.

```
Math.Round(0.345, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // returns 0.35
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding to [HoneyBadger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41592727/577765), you can use SQLCLR (as of SQL Server 2005) to expose the .NET `Math.Round()` method to T-SQL so that it can be used in queries.

You can either code this yourself, or you can simply download the Free version of the [SQL#](https://sqlsharp.com/?ref=so_55542163) SQLCLR library (which I created, and contains both **Math_RoundToEvenFloat** and **Math_RoundToEvenDecimal** in the Free version), and then do:

```sql
SELECT ROUND(0.045, 2), SQL#.Math_RoundToEvenFloat(0.045, 2);
-- 0.050    0.04

SELECT ROUND(0.055, 2), SQL#.Math_RoundToEvenFloat(0.055, 2);
-- 0.060    0.06
```

There are both "Float" and "Decimal" -specific functions for performance and accuracy reasons. `FLOAT` values transfer between T-SQL and CLR contexts much faster, but can sometimes contain an extra 0.000000000005 (or something like that) coming into the CLR code, so be sure to use the function that matches the datatype you are using. If you are doing financial calculations, then you should already be using `DECIMAL` (a precise datatype). If you are using `FLOAT` (an imprecise datatype) for financial calculations, you should really change that to `DECIMAL` sooner than later ;-).