# SQL join not equal condition returning some equal columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-server-2012

I'm running these two queries on the same tables. This query

```
SELECT * 
FROM @Table1 t1
JOIN @Table2 t2 ON t1.PersonID = t2.PersonID
```

returns 300 records (both tables have 300 records), doesn't exclude records where values don't match.

[image]

This query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM @Table1 t1
JOIN @Table2 t2 ON t1.PersonID = t2.PersonID AND t1.TestValue <> t2.ReportValue
```

returns 90 records:

[image]

2nd query excluded many of the records with same value but not all, it's supposed to return only 20 records.

Why would `<>` work on some records but not others? Both columns are float. Any ideas?

Comment: My guess would be that the values aren't actually equal, but that you're [seeing rounded values in the output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099575/full-precision-output-of-floating-point-types-in-sql-server-management-studio) so they *look* equal. Comparing floats is always going to be a little tricky; you may want to use an "epsilon" comparison rather than straight equality.

Comment: Are these all int Columns? if not maybe there is an extra white space , try using LTRIM and RTRIM with all columns in Join condition.

Comment: Are t1.TestValue and t2.ReportValue the same datatype?

Comment: If you can dump full create table statements for both tables, it would be helpful.

Comment: @M.Ali and @Kennah `Both columns are float`

Comment: Why are these columns float anyway?

Comment: Well here is your problem then, Float is an imaginary/Approximate Data type, These two values you have mentioned `8891` , in Float data type they are maybe representing two different values thats why you are getting them back. Use a fixed/Real data type like DECIMAL or NUMERIC and you will get the expected results back.

Comment: @M.Ali Converting columns to decimal, or keeping it as a float and using `convert(decimal(10,5), d.TestValue) <> convert(decimal(10,5), d2.ReportValue)` fixed it. Happy to accept it as an answer if you care to write one.

Answer (score 0):

What could be possible is that atleast one of your PersomID or ReportValue/TestValue columns could be in VARCHAR() data type, instead of INTEGER data type. If it is varchar data type, may be some of those values contain a space at the end which you aren't able to see right now.

So, if your ReportValue = 8991 AND TestValue = '8991 ', they will cause the condition to return a FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

just remove InnerJoin and do Left Join