# How Can I Get An Exact Character Representation of a Float in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, floating-point

We are doing some validation of data which has been migrated from one SQL Server to another SQL Server. One of the things that we are validating is that some numeric data has been transferred properly. The numeric data is stored as a float datatype in the new system.

We are aware that there are a number of issues with float datatypes, that exact numeric accuracy is not guaranteed, and that one cannot use exact equality comparisons with float data. We don't have control over the database schemas nor data typing and those are separate issues.

What we are trying to do in this specific case is verify that some ratio values were transferred properly. One of the specific data validation rules is that all ratios should be transferred with no more than 4 digits to the right of the decimal point.

So, for example, valid ratios would look like:

```
.7542
1.5423
```

Invalid ratios would be:

```
.12399794301
12.1209377
```

What we would like to do is count the number of digits to the right of the decimal point and find all cases where the float values have more than four digits to the right of it. We've been using the SUBSTRING, LEN, STR, and a couple of other functions to achieve this, and I am sure it would work if we had numeric fields typed as decimal which we were casting to char. 
However, what we have found when attempting to convert a float to a char value is that SQL Server seems to always convert to decimal in between. For example, the field in question shows this value when queried in SQL Server Enterprise Manager:

```
1.4667
```

Attempting to convert to a string using the recommended function for SQL Server:

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(field_name, 22, 17)))
```

Returns this value:

```
1.4666999999999999
```

The value which I would expect **if** SQL Server were directly converting from float to char (which we could then trim trailing zeroes from):

```
1.4667000000000000
```

Is there any way in SQL Server to convert directly from a float to a char without going through what appears to be an intermediate conversion to decimal along the way? We also tried the CAST and CONVERT functions and received similar results to the STR function.

SQL Server Version involved: SQL Server 2012 SP2

Thank you.

Comment: My guess is that the value actually is `1.4666999999999999`. When you select it in Enterprise Manager it's rounding it for you.

Comment: Assuming that these numbers are stored internally as 64-bit floating-point numbers according to the IEEE 754 standard, 1.4667 would be stored as a binary representation that (exactly) corresponds to the decimal number 1.466699999999999892708046900224871933460235595703125. Correctly rounded to 16 decimal places, that is 1.4666999999999999, which is precisely what you got. Perhaps you can round to fewer decimal places, so these small errors at the end will be hidden?

Comment: Thanks guys. I believe that both of you are correct and that the root of the issue is a) that there is no such exact number 1.4667 that can be represented as a float and b) that Enterprise Manager actually rounds these numbers before displaying them. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099575/full-precision-output-of-floating-point-types-in-sql-server-management-studio) gives a little more background on rounding in SQL Server management studio. We are trying using the other SQL clients mentioned in the linked article (e.g. SQLCMD) to verify the output that we get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your validation rule seems to be misguided.

An SQL Server `FLOAT`, or `FLOAT(53)`, is stored internally as a 64-bit floating-point number according to the IEEE 754 standard, with 53 bits of mantissa ("value") plus an exponent. Those 53 binary digits correspond to approximately 15 decimal digits.

Floating-point numbers have limited precision, which does not mean that they are "fuzzy" or inexact in themselves, but that not all numbers can be exactly represented, and instead have to be represented using *another* number.

For example, there is no exact representation for your **1.4667**, and it will instead be stored as a binary floating-point number that (exactly) corresponds to the decimal number **1.466699999999999892708046900224871933460235595703125**. Correctly rounded to 16 decimal places, that is **1.4666999999999999**, which is precisely what you got.

Since the "exact character representation of the float value that is in SQL Server" is **1.466699999999999892708046900224871933460235595703125**, the validation rule of "no more than 4 digits to the right of the decimal point" is clearly flawed, at least if you apply it to the "exact character representation".

What you might be able to do, however, is to round the stored number to fewer decimal places, so that the small error at the end of the decimals is hidden. Converting to a character representation rounded to 15 instead of 16 places (remember those "15 decimal digits" mentioned at the beginning?) will give you **1.466700000000000**, and then you can check that all decimals after the first four are zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `cast` to `varchar`.

```
select case when
len(
substring(cast(col as varchar(100))
          ,charindex('.',cast(col as varchar(100)))+1
          ,len(cast(col as varchar(100)))
         )
   ) = 4
then 'true' else 'false' end
from tablename
where charindex('.',cast(col as varchar(100))) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

For this particular number, don't use STR(), and use a convert or cast to varchar.  But, in general, you will always have precision issues when storing in float... it's the nature of the storage of that datatype.  The best you can do is normalize to a NUMERIC type and compare with threshold ranges (+/- .0001, for example).  See the following for a breakdown of how the different conversions work:

```
declare @float float = 1.4667
select  @float,
        convert(numeric(18,4), @float),
        convert(nvarchar(20), @float),
        convert(nvarchar(20), convert(numeric(18,4), @float)),
        str(@float, 22, 17),
        str(convert(numeric(18,4), @float)),
        convert(nvarchar(20), convert(numeric(18,4), @float))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of casting to a VarChar you might try this: cast to a decimal with 4 fractional digits and check if it's the same value as before.

```
case when field_name <> convert(numeric(38,4), field_name) 
     then 1 
     else 0 
end
```

Comment: While this is an interesting thing to verify, it's not exactly the question that I am asking. We have seen that this check will fail in a fair number of cases just due to the way that floats work in their conversion to decimal. That is a separate problem. For this question I just want to know how to get an exact character representation of the float value that is in SQL Server.

Comment: @magnum_pi: Well, you know that FLOAT is not exact, but want an exact representation :) You might subtract both values and check if the difference is outside of a margin-

Comment: @dnoeth: Well, to be fair, FLOAT values _are_ exact. It's just that not all numbers can be exactly represented using the exact values that exist.

Comment: The question wasn't about an exact abstract representation of a float. The question was "why can't I get a character conversion output of what seems to be the float value stored in SQL Server, which is '1.4667'?" The issue turns out to be that my question assumed that '1.4667' was the actual float value stored in internally in SQL Server, which is not the case. I did not realize this because I did not realize that SQL Server Management Studio was rounding its display of floats.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have here is that float is an approximate number data type with an accuracy of about seven digits. That means it approaches the value while using less storage than a decimal / numeric. That's why you don't use float for values that require exact precision.
Check this example:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (
col FLOAT
)

INSERT into @t (col)
VALUES (1.4666999999999999)
,(1.4667)
,(1.12399794301)
,(12.1209377);

SELECT col
, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),col) AS chr
, CAST(col as VARBINARY) AS bin
, LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(col, 22, 17))) AS rec
FROM @t
```

As you see the float 1.4666999999999999 binary equals 1.4667. For your stated needs I think this query would fit:

```
SELECT col
, RIGHT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),col), LEN(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),col)) - CHARINDEX('.',CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),col))) AS prec
from @t
```

Comment: A minor detail: The data type `FLOAT` in SQL Server is equivalent to `FLOAT(53)`, with 53 bits of mantissa, and is equivalent to what many programming languages call "double", not "float". This is equivalent to about 15 decimal digits, not 7.