# How to find float rounding errors in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've narrowed down a data issue on a legacy SQL Server 2008 database.

The column is a 'float'. SSMS shows four of the records as '0.04445' but when i query for all records that match the first value, only 3 of the four are returned. The last record is somehow different, i suspect it is off by 0.0000000001 or something and the SMSS GUI is rounding it for display(?). Using the '<' operator has similar results ('where my_column < 0.04445' returns three of the four) This is causing some catastrophic calculation errors in the calling app.

I tried casting it to a decimal ('SELECT CAST(my_column as DECIMAL(38,20)) FROM...') but all four records just come back 0.044450000000000000000000000000

I suspect that there are many other similar errors in this same column, as the data has been entered in various ways over the years.

Is there any way to see this column in its full value/precision/mantissa, rather than the rounded value?

I can't change the schema or the app.

Update - using the 'Edit Top 200 Rows' feature, I can see that about three quarters of them are 0.044449999999999996 and the other quarter are ecxactly 0.04445. But I can't get it to display that level of accuracy in a regular query result

Comment: to find floats you can do something like `abs(desired_value - found_value) < epsilon * desired_value` where epsilon is a measure for the acceptable precision

Comment: @Ronald I tried 
`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE
abs(0.04445 - my_column) < 0.0000001 * 0.04445` 
for epsilons of 0.0000001 and 0.1, and they both return the same results, (was expecting about 1/4 of them to be different between the two result sets) so I think it must be rounding before doing that result? Or maybe I am misunderstanding your comment?

Comment: _Prior to SQL Server 2016 (13.x), conversion of float values to decimal or numeric is restricted to values of precision 17 digits only. Any float value less than 5E-18 (when set using either the scientific notation of 5E-18 or the decimal notation of 0.0000000000000000050000000000000005) rounds down to 0. This is no longer a restriction as of SQL Server 2016 (13.x)._

Comment: _Values of float are truncated when they are converted to any integer type_

Comment: @Fabio This seems to be related to the root of it; looks like the 17th digit is the important one (ie the 6 in 0.044449999999999996). So I can at least  get a value by this:
`SELECT DISTINCT CAST(my_column*10 AS decimal(17,17)) FROM my_table
WHERE my_column< 0.1
ORDER BY CAST(my_column*10 AS decimal(17,17))`
But I need the WHERE clause, because the precision of other values in the column vary wildly (causing rounding). I don't think I can award bounty to a comment rather than an answer?

Comment: @bitcoder, I just copy-paste quote from documentation [float and real (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Floats always have this behaviour. People so often confuse accuracy and precision, causing them to think floats are more accurate than decimals. Floats can have greater precision, but are inherently binary estimates and are rarely absolutely accurate. A float, for example, can never be 0.2 exactly. ***Never***. So, if you find these rogue values, what do you want to ***do*** next? Either the code should reflect the behaviour of floats, or the table altered to use decimals instead. Probably. I don't see how finding individual cases is really going to help. (Though the VARBINARY answer may help)

Comment: Also, floats don't have a precision component in the binary value. They have a mantissa which is always "zero point something" (0 <= m < 1) and an exponent (and a sign bit). The closest to a precision you get is the size of the data type (32bit, 64bit, etc).

Comment: On some w3schools web site I was able to test some statements against SQL Server. The statement `SELECT 1 where Abs(0.04445e0 - 0.044449999999999996e0) < 0.0000000001e0 * 0.04445e0;` behaved absolutely correctly and returned a row. To me this shows that SQL Server (don't know what release is in use) doesn't have a problem. If there is an intermediate system that parses the statement before it rebuilds it again and sends it to the DBMS engine, the problem could lie there. I don't know the SSMS GUI though, so I can't tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, your question is really about SSMS, not about your application or SQL Server itself, right? You want to see the actual `float` values in SSMS without rounding, right?

By design SSMS rounds `float` during display. For example, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8099730/4116017).

But, you can see the actual value that is stored in the column if you convert it to a string explicitly using [`CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#float-and-real-styles) function.

> **float and real styles**
>
> For a **float** or **real** expression, style can have
> one of the values shown in the following table. Other values are
> processed as 0.
>
> 0 (default)   A maximum of 6 digits. Use in scientific notation, when appropriate.
>
> 1 Always 8 digits. Always use in scientific notation.
>
> 2 Always 16 digits. Always use in scientific notation.
>
> 3 Always 17 digits. Use for lossless conversion.
> With this style, every distinct float or real value is guaranteed to
> convert to a distinct character string.

It looks like style 3 is just what you need:

```
convert(varchar(30), my_column, 3)
```

Here is my test:

```
DECLARE @v1 float = 0.044449999999999996e0;
DECLARE @v2 float = 0.044445e0;

SELECT @v1, @v2, convert(varchar(30), @v1, 3), convert(varchar(30), @v2, 3)
```

Result that I see in SSMS:

```
+------------------+------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| (No column name) | (No column name) | (No column name)        | (No column name)        |
+------------------+------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 0.04445          | 0.044445         | 4.4449999999999996e-002 | 4.4444999999999998e-002 |
+------------------+------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Antonin Lejsek's answer is just as technically correct, but this is a lot more readable. 
Note that the version of SMSS that comes with SQL Server 2008 doesn't support style 3 (looks like that was introduced in SMSS 2016).

Comment: @bitcoder, oh, indeed, it looks like the style 3 was introduced in SQL Server 2016 (not SSMS, the SQL Server itself. The version of SSMS doesn't matter, the version of the SQL engine matters). Style 3 is a parameter of `CONVERT` function and MS must have upgraded how this function works in SQL Server 2016. `CONVERT` function converts the `float` value into a string and SSMS simply shows that string. In 2008 you can convert `float` to `binary` and at least see that the values are different. Another option for 2008 that comes to mind is to write your own conversion function using C# & CLR.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `CONVERT(VARBINARY(8), my_column)` to the number in its original form. What you get should be `0x3FA6C226809D4952` or `0x3FA6C226809D4951`. And what number that really is? 3FA6C226809D4951 is binary

```
0 01111111010 0110110000100010011010000000100111010100100101010001
0 => number is positive
01111111010 => 1018-1023 = -5 is exponent (so we get 2^-5)
1.0110110000100010011010000000100111010100100101010001 => 6405920109971793*2^-52
```

so the 0x3FA6C226809D4951 is exactly 6405920109971793*2^-57, which is 0.044449999999999996458388551445750636048614978790283203125

and 0x3FA6C226809D4952 is exactly 6405920109971794*2^-57, which is 0.04445000000000000339728245535297901369631290435791015625