# Why is SQL Server adding numbers to the end of my round?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server and it is currently the program I'd like to stick with, this is the code

```
SELECT 
    ROUND(CONVERT(DOUBLE PRECISION, SUM(lat_n)), 2),
    ROUND(CONVERT(DOUBLE PRECISION, SUM(long_w)),2) 
FROM
    station;
```

When I just round it works fine, but then there's floating zeros after, and I need them gone. When I try to convert the values these are the results I get-

```
  42850.040000000001   47381.480000000003
```

Why is it adding those random numbers on the end, how do I stop it and is there a better way to get rid of floating 0's in SQL Server?

Comment: You stated to the RDBMS you want a floating point value, and that's what you have. If you want a precise value, use a precise data type.

Comment: (Side note, that *is* valid T-SQL syntax, you learn something every day. Why you would use that syntax though is another question.)

Comment: `double precision` is equivalent to float(53)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand floating point then, should I use decimal data type?

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-2/problem    @Larnu  it was to solve this, I'm open to hear how I could have done it better.

Comment: I recommend doing some research so you understand the issue e.g. https://blog.greglow.com/2018/01/15/sql-newbie-mistake-1-using-float-instead-decimal/

Comment: My point is, if you want a specific number of decimal places, then using a floating point data type is completely the wrong choice.

Comment: @DaleK thank you for the blog, i get it now. My problem is SQL SERVER only takes away floating zeros for floating type numbers apparently. In order to solve these problems properly I need a way to get rid of them, and even decimal type leaves them behind. I guess that's my new problem now

Comment: decimal types might still produce additional decimal places, but they will all be zero, and therefore not affect the actual number. Only floats get strange fractions added.

Comment: Not "strange fractions". If you work through how a floating point number is stored in binary, there are simply limitations to how the fractional part can be represented. More info [what every programmer should know about floating point arithmetic](https://floating-point-gui.de/)

Answer (score 1):

`DOUBLE PRECISION` (which equivalent to `float(53)` here) is the wrong choice here.

Try either `NUMERIC(18,2)` or `DECIMAL(18,2)`

- [float and real](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [decimal and numeric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Note that SSMS rounds the output of floating-point types for display purposes but it doesn't apply to others, for example in the link you provided in the comments. That's probably you see the different behavior.

[Full precision output of floating point types in SQL Server Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099575/full-precision-output-of-floating-point-types-in-sql-server-management-studio)